# How change delay time of callbackQuery clocks? in telegram bot sdk php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

How can i minimize long pending of clocks display?

I use telegram bot sdk php in laravel, all works fine, but when I click on inline button I handle callback_data pending clocks not hidding.
I try to reply with answer with answerCallBackQuery , but nothing changed.
Please help me.

[image: clocks]

```
    $inline_keyboard[] = [
      [
       'text' =>'20-30',
       'callback_data' => 'age.2'
      ],
      [
       'text' =>'30-40',
       'callback_data' => 'age.3'
      ]
    ];

   $reply_markup = Telegram::replyKeyboardMarkup([
      'inline_keyboard' => $inline_keyboard,
      'resize_keyboard' => true
   ]);

   $this->replyWithMessage([
          'text' => 'How old are you?',
          'reply_markup' => $reply_markup,
  ]);
```

Comment: I don't see any `answerCallbackQuery` calls in your code above. To "remove" the clock icon, you need to call `answerCallbackQuery` with at least callback query id as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this

```
Telegram::answerCallbackQuery([
       'callback_query_id' => $callback_id
            ]);
```

Where your $callback_id is :

```
 $query = $update->getCallbackQuery();
 $callback_id = $query->getId();
```

Where $update is :

```
$update = Telegram::commandsHandler(true);
```